# Return to a specific dialog

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a very simple text editor and have run into a somewhat minor problem. Code below

Saving a file, when a file exists, the user will be prompted to overwrite, cancel, or not overwrite (having the option to try again).

So I have a JFileChooser that will prompt the user to overwrite: yes, no, cancel

In the case of no being selected, it should return to the JFileChoose dialog, but I just plain don't know how. Can anyone help me out on this? The cancel and yes options aren't any problems (as far as I'm aware, haven't tested in depth)

```
String contents = textArea.getText();
if (openPath != null) {
    savePath = openPath;                    
} else if (saveAsPath != null) {
    savePath = saveAsPath;
} else if (savePath != null) {
    savePath = savePath;
} else if (openPath == null) {
    JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = saveFile.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == saveFile.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        savePath = saveFile.getSelectedFile();
        if (!savePath.exists()) {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter (savePath);
        BufferedWriter saveWrite = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        saveWrite.write(contents);
        saveWrite.close();
        } else if (savePath.exists()) {
            JOptionPane overwritePrompt = new JOptionPane();
            Object[] options = {"Yes","No","Cancel"};
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(overwritePrompt,
               "Already exists. Overwrite?","Overwrite File?", 
               JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
               null,options,options[2]);
        if (n == 0) {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(saveAsPath);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(contents);
        out.close();
        } else if (n == 1) {
            savePath = null;
            openPath = null;
            saveAsPath = null;
            return; // should return to JFileChooser
        } else {
                savePath = null;
            openPath = null;
            saveAsPath = null;
            return;
        }
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about starting over at this line:

```
int returnVal = saveFile.showOpenDialog(null);
```

again, when you should return to the JFileChooser? I assume that the same file chooser
would display its open dialog again then?

Comment: Wow, that sucks.

Thanks man - Feels horrible destroying that code but you're dead right. I never looked much into JChooseFile - just went by example